# How to get the child nodes from the data I inserted into Listview?

Tags: java, android

I've created a Listview and inserted data from my SQLite databse into it. The OnItemClick on the Listview opens up another fragment, but I can only access the name displayed on the listItem. How do I get the rest of the data?

Using getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); works for the item clicked, but not for the rest of the data. getChildAt(position).toString(); doesn't work either. I've also tried with a StringBuffer, but couldn't make it work (I might not have done it right). Can anyone help me here?

```
public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {


    ImageButton addFood;
    ListView listView;
    FoodDatabaseHelper mFoodDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);

        addFood = view.findViewById(R.id.addFood);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEaten);
        mFoodDatabaseHelper = new FoodDatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populateListview();


        return view;
    }

    private void populateListview(){
        //populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = mFoodDatabaseHelper.getData();
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                list.add(data.getString(1));
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            //Get data from Listview
                            String food = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            String protein = listView.getChildAt(position).toString();
                            String fats = listView.getChildAt(position).toString();
                            String carbo = listView.getChildAt(position).toString();

                            Cursor data = mFoodDatabaseHelper.getFood(food);
                            int itemID = -1;
                            while (data.moveToNext()){
                                itemID = data.getInt(0);
                            }
                            if(itemID > -1){
                                FoodDetailFragment frt = new FoodDetailFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                                //Send the relevant data to the FoodDetailFragment
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("foods", food);
                                bundle.putString("protein", protein);
                                bundle.putString("fats", fats);
                                bundle.putString("carbo", carbo);
                                frt.setArguments(bundle);
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frt);
                                transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No such ID ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next fragment should show the name of the food and the macros, for example:

```
Bacon

1

0

18
```

Instead it displays:

```
Bacon 

android.support.v7.widget.AppcompatTextView{82d2539V.ED..... ..... 0
0-974,123£1020014android:id/text1}

android.support.v7.widget.AppcompatTextView{82d2539V.ED..... ..... 0
0-974,123£1020014android:id/text1}

android.support.v7.widget.AppcompatTextView{82d2539V.ED..... ..... 0
0-974,123£1020014android:id/text1}
```

I can't figure out how to point at the value. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

**EDIT:** I have now changed the code trying to follow the link provided. This had lead me to be able to get the childnodes. I ended up with this. It's not pretty, but it works.

```
public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {

    String food, proteins, fats, carbohydrates;
    ImageButton addFood;
    FoodDatabaseHelper foodDatabaseHelper;
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> foodlist;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);

        addFood = view.findViewById(R.id.addFood);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEaten);
        foodDatabaseHelper = new FoodDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        addFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TrackingFragment frt = new TrackingFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frt);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        foodlist = new ArrayList<>();
        populateListview();

        return view;
    }

    private void populateListview() {

        Cursor cursor = foodDatabaseHelper.getData();
        foodlist.clear();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                food = cursor.getString(1);
                proteins = cursor.getString(2);
                fats = cursor.getString(3);
                carbohydrates = cursor.getString(4);

                HashMap<String, String> foods = new HashMap<>();
                foods.put("foods", food);
                foods.put("proteins", proteins);
                foods.put("fats", fats);
                foods.put("carbohydrates", carbohydrates);
                foodlist.add(foods);
                cursor.moveToNext();

            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), foodlist, R.layout.fragment_food_items, new String[]{"foods", "proteins", "fats", "carbohydrates"}, new int[]{R.id.food, R.id.proteins, R.id.fats, R.id.carbs});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some major problems with your code :

1. Don't initialise listview adapter and onItemClickListener() inside a while loop. These should be outside the loop.
2. If you want to fetch all the data at a position when you click on a listitem, then you should create a class and store objects of that class in your List instead of just a string.

This link has some code that will help you to correct yours https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-show-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-listview/

Comment: Let me know if you had any trouble. And if this solved your problem, please mark it as an answer for others to follow.

Comment: Update. With this link and some other stuff, I made it work. Thanks for your help!